# Specify which project to debug when attaching to process

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

How can I specify which project in the solution to debug when attaching to a process, preventing Visual Studio 2010 from starting all other web-based projects in the solution, too?

I hate it that every time I attach to a process to debug one web project in the solution, it automatically builds and starts running all other web projects; can I prevent that without having to take them in their own solutions?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're confusing the terms a bit here.  It sounds like when you say "Attaching to Process" you really mean "Start debugging by pressing F5", is that the case? If so, to control which projects start up when you hit F5, right click your solution in Solution Explorer, and go to Common Properties->StartUp Porjects, and select the option you want.

Comment: No, I'm specifically saying "attach to process" (Debug -> Attach to Process).